# What is the difference between AVPlayerItem.duration and AVPlayerItem.asset.duration?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am KVO-ing the `AVPlayer.timeControlStatus` property, the player has a single `AVPlayerItem`.

The video is a `mpeg4` encoded 10s video file hosted on a remote server:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true])
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

let player = AVQueuePlayer()
player.actionAtItemEnd = .pause
player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
player.insert(item, after: nil)
```

When the property first changes to `.playing`, I look at the duration values in the debug console:

```
(lldb) po player.currentItem?.asset.duration
▿ Optional<CMTime>
  ▿ some : CMTime
    - value : 1281
    - timescale : 600
    ▿ flags : CMTimeFlags
      - rawValue : 1
    - epoch : 0

(lldb) po player.currentItem?.duration
▿ Optional<CMTime>
  ▿ some : CMTime
    - value : 0
    - timescale : 0
    ▿ flags : CMTimeFlags
      - rawValue : 17
    - epoch : 0
```

Why are these values different?

Answer (score 0):

when the `player.currentItem?.duration` is 0 means indefinite in other words you are playing a live stream.

I'm not sure but `player.currentItem?.asset.duration` is the total time where the user can move with the slider this can change with the time when the player is buffering

Comment: I've added the code to the question, the URL is not a HSL live stream, it's a remote `mp4` file.